# need to select an item based on the name in an array using powershell

Tags: powershell, audio, windows-10

Not even sure if i'm wording this right but here goes nothing: I have a script to toggle through audio devices. It will check the current set device based on Index number, and switch to the other one accordingly. My problem is, if i introduce a new device, the index numbers change. So i need to select the device based on name not index, how do I do that?

```
$audio = Get-DefaultAudioDevice
$Audio.Index
if ($audio.Index -eq '0') {
set-defaultaudiodevice 2
}  Else {
set-defaultaudiodevice 0
}
```

the output for `Get-AudioDevicelist` is as follows:

```
Index DeviceFriendlyname                       Device               
----- ------------------                       ------               
    0 Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio) CoreAudioApi.MMDevice
    1 LG TV-0 (NVIDIA High Definition Audio)   CoreAudioApi.MMDevice
    2 Speakers (Logitech G533 Gaming Headset)  CoreAudioApi.MMDevice
```

If i turn off the TV, the index number changes and then the script stops working. .Index will go by the first column, how do i make it look for "Logitech"
 or "Speakers"?

Comment: `Set-DefaultAudioDevice (Get-AudioDeviceList).Where({$_.DeviceFriendlyName -match 'Logitech'}).Index` should work if you have PowerShell v4 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's a `-Name` parameter I missed on [`set-defaultaudiodevice`](https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets), just changed `$audio.Index` to `.devicefriendlyname` and updated the `if` statement accordingly