# error defining array in a script, it works if typed out however

Tags: powershell, control-characters

I'm trying to create an audio toggle. I've written it before but new OS and dll updates forced me to rewrite it, the method i used previously doesn't seem to work any longer.
So right out of the gate my first line spits out this error:

```
$audio : The term '$audio' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.
At D:\audiochanger.ps1:1 char:1
+ $audio = Get-AudioDevice -playback
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($audio:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

but if i type in `$audio = Get-AudioDevice -playback` and then call `$audio`, it works perfectly fine. Whats going on?

```
$audio = Get-AudioDevice -playback
$audio.Name
if ($audio.Name -eq 'Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)') {
set-audiodevice 1 
}  Else {
set-audiodevice 2
}
```

output of `Get-AudioDevice -playback`

```
Index   : 2
Default : True
Type    : Playback
Name    : Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)
ID      : {0.0.0.00000000}.{2aa2a27b-4ebc-4355-bdf7-093a8f97ba46}
Device  : CoreAudioApi.MMDevice

or

Index   : 1
Default : True
Type    : Playback
Name    : Speakers (Logitech G533 Gaming Headset)
ID      : {0.0.0.00000000}.{1f5d6b65-fe9b-4bda-9508-d1a204149395}
Device  : CoreAudioApi.MMDevice
```

this is running on windows 10 and powershell 5. my previous working code can be found here: [need to select an item based on the name in an array using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361611/need-to-select-an-item-based-on-the-name-in-an-array-using-powershell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only plausible explanation is that you have *invisible control characters* before `$audio` in your script file.

If your line truly started with `$audio = ...` it would be interpreted as an *assignment*, as intended; instead, what *looks like* `$audio` is being interpreted as the name of a *command*, which implies that `$` is not actually the 1st character.

You can reproduce the problem as follows:

```
[char] 0x200b + '$audio = Get-AudioDevice -playback' > t.ps1
./t.ps1
```

The above yields the error you saw, due to invisible control character `U+200B`([ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b))) preceding `$audio`.

While this particular control character is just an example, you can inspect the actual characters on your script's first line as follows:

```
 & { 
   [int[]] [char[]] $Args[0] | % { '0x{0:x} [{1}]' -f $_, [char] $_ } 
 } (get-content D:\audiochanger.ps1)[0]
```

The solution is to remove the invisible character(s); the following *may* work, depending on what characters are actually present in your case:

```
 (Get-Content D:\audiochanger.ps1) -replace '\p{Cf}' > D:\audiochanger.CleanedUp.ps1
```

Regex `\p{Cf}` matches all instances of invisible control characters
.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @acme64.